# Another highcharts 4.1.1 discrepancy (bug?) -- re pointPlacement

Tags: highcharts

Consider the following jsfiddle in which the columns are given a pointPlacement of -0.5 in order to have them sit to the left of the corresponding points from the spline.

This is important in my particular application, and particularly important that the spline point and offset column are treated together, as the same timepoint, for example as evidenced by the shared tooltip showing both values in the same bubble:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/ge2soL8r/5/

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPlacement: -0.5
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
```

Now the exact same code, but using highcharts 4.1.1:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/ge2soL8r/6/

Rather messily, and unfortunately, the two series have become unlinked as far as the tooltip is concerned, so that the bubble alternates showing values from the column and then the spline. This is surely not what is intended, and surely the behaviour should be as it was in 4.0.4?

Thanks!

Comment: Open this is a bug on their GitHub: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues

Comment: Thanks for pointing this possibility out.  I've opened this as an issue [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3912)